# I get this Tomcat Error on a dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

```
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:proiect' did not find a matching property.
Oct 18, 2015 11:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proiect]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1912)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [Test1] and [test.TestServlet1] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/test1] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2428)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2103)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2064)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2057)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1304)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5405)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

Oct 18, 2015 11:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor D:\allkind\AC\LTW\R1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\proiect.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proiect]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1912)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Oct 18, 2015 11:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor D:\allkind\AC\LTW\R1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\proiect.xml has finished in 43 ms
Oct 18, 2015 11:25:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 18, 2015 11:25:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 18, 2015 11:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 714 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be causing the deployment error:

java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [Test1] and [test.TestServlet1] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/test1] which is not permitted

You should look into your web.xml file and update the mapping for one of these servlets to different url-pattern.

Comment: this is the content of web.xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>test.TestServlet1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/test1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: this web.xml only has one servlet and servlet-mapping, which is pointing to /test1. Please can you make sure if you have the right one in the war file? Check the web.xml in your war file.